# android socket client pc server using asynctask

Tags: android, sockets, android-asynctask

I'm using asynctask to make connection between client (runnning on my android device) and server(running on my pc). When i launch the app i have to click on button to connect them, and my server pc program should show me in console device if client is connected but doesn't appear; my android client doesn't connect to my pc server.

Android client:

```
 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button send;
    EditText txt;
    TextView testo;
    String response = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
        //txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        testo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    }


    class AddStringTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) { 

            try {
                Socket socketClient = new Socket("10.10.0.151",4321); //ipaddress of my pc server
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                response = e.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                response = e.toString();
            }
            testo.setText(response);
            return (null);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... item) {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            testo.setText(response);
        }
    }

    public void buttonClick(View v){
        new AddStringTask().execute();
    }
}
```

Pc server:

```
public class Server {

public static Socket connection;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    System.out.println("Starting server on port number: 4321...");
    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(4321);

    while(true){
        System.out.println("Waiting for clients...");
        connection = server.accept();
        System.out.println("Connected to: "+connection.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());
        connection.close();

    }
}
```

}

In my AndroidManifest.xml i've just added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

If i launch client from pc in my server console i see the device connected but on android doesn't work..why?

Thanks

Comment: Make sure you have the correct IP of your Server and that you have turned off the firewall on your PC (sometimes it disallow connections)

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely the ip in the android side is wrong. use a private ip eg: 192.168.1.x. theese types of ip require you be on the same network. i think what you're trying to do is access the server from outside of the network and that requires port fkrwarding.